# Cancelling timeToLive cache expiration in EhCache if my database is down?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have a Spring 3.0.x web project that is displaying a page of links to users, and I have run into a bit of a puzzle. Currently, I am using EhCache 2.1.0 to cache my content, which is all static content that changes about once in a blue moon. The content itself is stored in a database that could go down, but will not effect many of the links that are displayed on the page, and I do not care about where those links go, I am only concerned with displaying them.

My puzzle is: how do I add a pre-check to EhCache's timeToLive so that it pings the database before expiring the cache? What I want it to do is ping the database, and if it is not up, skip the clear the cache, and reset the timer to check again in timeToLive seconds.

After looking through the documentation on ehcache.org, and reading through their cache manager and [cache event listeners](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners), [cache pinning](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/data-life) and [cache extensions](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-extensions), I was unable to find anything that would help guarantee me a way to do this... I am beginning to lean toward just setting timeToLive to 0 and implementing my own version of timeToLive, but it would be nice if I could just use something already present in EhCache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up creating my own cache expiration handling service and turning of ehcache's. The service works as follows:

- There are a handful of databases I use that have my static content. I declared these database in an enum.
- I then created a cache expiration metadata class that holds: (1) cache key, (2) time to live, (3) last refresh time, (4) database dependencies (list of enum vals), (5) spring bean id which holds #6, (6) user-defined cache expiration method name.
- I separated my cached method calls by database, and via xml, I created a metadata bean for each.
- At run time, each of these metadata beans are pushed into the service's internal map of cachekey -> metadata bean
- In the service, I have ping methods for each database to determine if they are up or not
- I then disabled the timetolive for ehcache by setting timeToLive to 0

This service has its own method for checking if a cache is expired or not, called it service.checkExpiration(cacheKey). If the cache for cacheKey is expired, I ping each of the metadata bean's dependencies, and if they are all up, I dynamically invoke the user-defined cache expiration method name.

So that is the guts of the cache expiration service. The actual implementation on the user side has at least two routes:

- You can wrap every @Ehcache annotated method call in a method that makes a call to the above service.. then, in your calling code, you call the wrapper method. This can get nasty if you have a lot of methods
- Or, you can use Spring AOP and the @Before annotation to hook into the method call, and make the cache expiration checking call.

I am trying out the latter, as it is less cluttery, although quite a bit more magicky which I don't like. So far it is looking pretty good. I really wish ehcache had supported some kind of pre-execution method though, it would have saved me a lot of time developing this... though not been nearly as fun :)

Comment: This has been successful for me, and simplified database down timebombs. I am working on making the cache even more robust so that it auto-fills on command/after database comes back up.